# Find all modes in a bimodal+ list

Tags: python

I have some code in which the user will input a list of data, e.g. `[4,5,3,4,2,3,4,5]`. The purpose of my code is to summarize the data, giving values like median, mean, and mode. The problem is that if the user inputs a list in which it has multiple modes, e.g. `[4,5,3,4,2,3,4,5,3,5]` it only displays the lowest value, in this case, it would display 3. I have tried many methods of finding mode, all of which give me the same result.

```
mode = max(set(user_input), key=user_input.count)
```

```
modes = []
    for key, value in user_input.items():
      if most_values == value:
        modes.append(key)
    number_of_modes = len(modes)
    if number_of_modes == 1:
        print('There is only one mode: {}'.format(modes[0]))
    else:
        print('There are {} modes:'.format(number_of_modes))
        for mode in modes:
            print(mode)
```

```
counter = Counter(user_input)
    mode = max(set(user_input), key=user_input.count)
```

If someone could give me an answer, that would be very useful, thanks. Also, I'm sorry if this question is answered somewhere else, I've tried to find it, and couldn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to write code from scratch for all cases, especially if someone has already solved it.

For your problem, you can use the function `multimode` from the `statistics` package:

```
import statistics
user_input = [4,5,3,4,2,3,4,5,3,5]
statistics.multimode(user_input)
```

Output:

```
[4, 5, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

Following the OP's original idea with `Counter`.

```
lst = [4,5,3,4,2,3,4,5,3,5]

c = Counter(lst)
# get the 1st candidate for the mode
mode, f_mode = max(c.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])

# get all other candidates by filtering wrt the highest frequency
modes = [k for k, v in c.items() if v == f_mode]

# check the output
print(modes)
#[4, 5, 3]
```

or, thanks for input of *pho*,

```
mode, _ = max(c.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])

modes = list(dict(c.most_common(lst.count(mode))))
```

Comment: `Counter` has a `most_common` method https://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common

Comment: The problem is that `most_common` doesn't group per frequency so you can get also values which are not _mode_. I found also `zip(*c.most_common(lst.count(mode)))` but... maybe are less intuitive:) Thanks anyway!

Comment: I meant you could use `most_common` to get the value of the `mode`, but I'm not sure this would be any faster.  You'd still need to iterate over all values in the counter to get all items whose count is `mode`.